# Horizontal menu showing vertically with cssfriendly adapter

Tags: css-friendly

I am using cssfriendly latest version but while applyinf Orientation="Horizntal" my manu shows in Verticle format.

Below is my .ASPX code

`<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" CssSelectorClass="PrettyMenu"
StaticDisplayLevels="2"  Orientation="Horizontal" />`

Sitemap code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home page for site">
    <siteMapNode url="about/default.aspx" title="About"  description="About Us" />
    <siteMapNode url="help/default.aspx" title="Help"  description="FAQs and SiteMap">
      <siteMapNode url="help/faq.aspx" title="FAQ"  description="Frequently Asked Questions" />
      <siteMapNode url="help/sitemap.aspx" title="Sitemap"  description="Map of Site" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Please let me suggest any way to resplve this problem.

Comment: Horizontal menu will show root nodes horizontally and childs vertically. you have only one root node ie "home". So there is no other menu item to be shown horizontally. And also the static display level is 2, this make it look like a vertical menu. Try to add another root node which will make it clear for you

Comment: Hi, Thnaks for quick reply will you please show me in above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home page for site">
    <siteMapNode url="help/default.aspx" title="Help"  description="FAQs and SiteMap">
      <siteMapNode url="help/faq.aspx" title="FAQ"  description="Frequently Asked Questions" />
      <siteMapNode url="help/sitemap.aspx" title="Sitemap"  description="Map of Site" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="about/default.aspx" title="About"  description="About Us" />
</siteMap>
```

Please try this, This will show two menu items "Home" and "About" horozontally, with their childs vertically.